# Freeze when try to access DVDRW

Tags: freeze

I'm running 18.04 on an hp 15-db0069hw laptop.  The hp DVDRW
works fine in Windows (dual-booted).  If I try to play a DVD in Ubuntu, it usually does the first time, but if I try a second one, it freezes.  Then, even lshw freezes; and if I try to access the drive (say, with Handbrake) or mount it (/dev/sr0), or use "eject", these all freeze.  Opening and closing the drive, etc, does not work.  I tried lsmod, before and after the freeze, to see if I could learn something about drivers, but there was no change.  Once this freezing begins, even shutting down Ubuntu freezes.  But on rebooting I (usually) get another play on the drive.

Any thoughts would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The freezing is only of the terminal posting the command.  Everything else (including playing a DVD on an external drive) works just fine.